# Python Circular Dependencies and Object Instanstiation

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I know, that this has already been answered multiple times. But I am still running into circular import. Here is example of my code.And I don't understand where is a circular dependency happening here.

A.py

```
from B import B
from C import C
  
def func():
    #using B and C object separately
    pass
```

**init**.py(Module B)

```
from C import C

class B():
  #this is a an object of type P which uses C object as constructor
  P(C)
```

**init**.py(Module C)

```
class C():
  #this is object of type P which has no dependency on B
  P()
```

Now here, I am importing both B and C object in the A.py file. B is dependent on C and B and C are of object type P. And I am getting error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name C from partially initialized import from C module (Most likely due to circular import)
```

I have tried pycycle package to check circular import but it passed test and no circular import was found.I am initializing B and C separately in A.py file. What can be the issue. Again, both B and C are comparatively large and inherit from same type of object.

And what is this partially initialized module?

Comment: What is `P` and the file that defines it?

Comment: P is type of object and B and C object inherits from type P object.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that in the question. Are you sure the file that contains the definition of `P` isn't importing something that's then importing `B` or `C`?

Comment: yes, positive on that part. P uses other object and does not mention B and C in file.